# Converting double to int is giving unexpected results

Tags: c++, int, double, pow

I was trying to find cube root of a perfect  cube using pow function but the answers were unexpected (3375 = 15^3)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double cb = pow(3375, 1.0/3.0);
    printf("cb(in double) = %lf\n", cb);
    printf("cb(in int) = %d\n",(int)cb);
    return 0;
}
```

the output it shows is :

```
cb(in double) = 15.000000
cb(in int) = 14
```

After discussing it with people it turned out that the code ,

```
printf("%0.0lf", 14.0/3);
```

gives output

```
5
```

I am not getting why it's happening, and if it's due to precision in storing double and rounding off, then it should round it down to a smaller value rather than rounding to a greater value.

Comment: Converting `double` to `int` rounds towards 0.

Comment: If what you saying i scorrect then why 14.0/3 is giving output as 5

Comment: Perhaps in your machine `cb` results in something a bit over 15, say 15.000000003 which rounds to int 15. Or it's 14.9999999966?

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: 14.0/3 yields 4.666666.  When you round 4.666666 up you get 5.

Comment: You should use your debugger to see the actual value instead of using `printf`.

Comment: Just use `printf("%f\n", 14.0/3);` and you will be fine.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's giving the same answer with cout and setprecision(0)

Comment: 4.6667 rounded to 0 decimal places is 5 – it isn't obvious why you're puzzled.  What else would you expect?  Assignment is different from printing.  And `printf("%d\n", (int)(14.0/3));` would yield 4.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it's giving the same output on using cstdio cmath and iostream as headers instead of bits/stdc++.h

Comment: @prashantshishodiap  The point is that you are relying on output functions instead of viewing the actual value.  That is not a good way to determine the actual value.  Use the debugger.

Comment: You are printing 4.666666... with a precision of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: `(int)double` always rounds towards zero. `printf("%0.0lf", double)` actually rounds to closest integer.

---

When you convert the double to int, then the result is rounded towards zero. E.g. `(int)14.9999` is 14, not 15. Therefore your first example with `pow()` must have given you the result slightly below 15, therefore direct cast to int gives 14.

Now, when you use printf(), then other rules are used. Printf, when asked to print a double using smallest number of digits possible (`%0.0lf`) rounds it to the closest integer, therefore `printf("%0.0lf", 14.666)` prints 15.